# MUI Autocomplete (multiple) controlled values - mysterious input behavior

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to write code to asynchronously search a multiple-select combo upon keyboard entry.

However I found in latest version (5.2.2) a strange behaviour where I cannot explain. I distill the issue below (based on example from MUI's autocomplete page):

```js
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";

const options = [
  { label: "Option 1", value: 1 },
  { label: "Option 2", value: 2 }
];

export default function ControllableStates() {
  // const [value, setValue] = React.useState<any | null>([]);
  const value = [];
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");

  console.log("Current Value:", value);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{`value: ${value !== null ? `'${value}'` : "null"}`}</div>
      <div>{`inputValue: '${inputValue}'`}</div>
      <br />
      <Autocomplete
        multiple={true}
        value={value}
        onChange={(event: any, newValue: any | null) => {
          //setValue(newValue);
        }}
        inputValue={inputValue}
        onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
          setInputValue(newInputValue);
        }}
        id="controllable-states-demo"
        options={options}
        sx={{ width: 300 }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Controllable" />}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The codeSandbox is as follows: https://codesandbox.io/s/controllablestates-material-demo-forked-ygqp2?file=/demo.tsx

If you try in the codeSandbox, you will be unable to type anything in the TextField field.

However, if you switch the commenting:

```js
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<any | null>([]);
  // const value = [];
```

You will be able to type in the TextField field. What is actually happening here? The value did not change at all.

Can anyone figure out why my first code (where the value is a const empty array) didn't work?

The reason I am asking is that I need to pass in the (controlled) value as props, and then set it to default to [] if it is null. I find that I am unable to type in the TextField due to this defaulting.

Comment: Additional note: I think I figured out that Autocomplete is clearing the inputValue each time the value changed (using useState, the initial array reference is persisted with every render, whereas without useState, the [] is a new reference every time it rerenders).

The question is: should this be the right behaviour, or should inputValue be persisted even if value changed? In the documentation it is stated that:  *⚠️ These two states are isolated, they should be controlled independently* (https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#controlled-states). I believe this should be respected.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `react-hook-form` you can set up the autocomplete by using

- `multiple` to add multiple values,
- `options`: you add the options to be selected
- `getOptionLabel`: to show up the label of the options
- `onChange`: use onChange function of `react-hook-form` to set the selected values
- `renderInput`: to render the input

```js
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form'
import {
  Box,
  TextField,
  Autocomplete,
} from '@mui/material'

const {
  ...
  control,
  formState: { errors },
} = useForm()

<Box mt={2}>
  <Controller
    control={control}
    name="industries"
    rules={{
      required: 'Veuillez choisir une réponse',
    }}
    render={({ field: { onChange } }) => (
      <Autocomplete
        defaultValue={
          useCasesData?.industries
            ? JSON.parse(useCasesData?.industries)
            : []
        }
        multiple
        disableCloseOnSelect
        options={companyIndustryTypes}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
        onChange={(event, values) => {
          onChange(values)
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Type d'industries"
            placeholder="Type d'industries"
            helperText={errors.industries?.message}
            error={!!errors.industries}
          />
        )}
      />
    )}
  />
</Box>
```

> Note that options in my case `companyIndustryTypes` is an array of object :

```json
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Accounting",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Administration & Office Support",
    },
    ...
]
```

[image]

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for the past hour, tysm

Answer (score 2):

First, you could use the `Autocomplete` component without `inputValue` and `OnInputValue` props.

```
      ...
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        value={value}
        onChange={(event: any, newValue: any | null) => {
          //setValue(newValue);
        }}
        id="controllable-states-demo"
        options={options}
        sx={{ width: 300 }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Controllable" />}
      />
```

But it won't work for the selection, only search will work.

Second, if you want its search as well as selection to work, then you should use more a couple of [Autocomplete props](https://mui.com/api/autocomplete/#props).

```
...
export default function ControllableStates() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<any | null>([]);
  // you need to set the selected value your own
  // const value = [];
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");

  console.log("Current Value:", value);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{`value: ${value !== null ? `'${value}'` : "null"}`}</div>
      <div>{`inputValue: '${inputValue}'`}</div>
      <br />
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        value={value}
        onChange={(event: any, newValue: any | null) => {
          setValue(newValue.map(option => option.value || option));
        }}
        isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.value === value}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => {
          if (typeof option === 'number') {
            return options.find(item => item.value === option)?.label;
          } else {
            return option.label;
          }
        }}
        id="controllable-states-demo"
        options={options}
        sx={{ width: 300 }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Controllable" />}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you can see it doesn't need to use the `inputValue` and `onInputChange` props as well.

Please make sure if you match the correct types of the selected value and option.