# material ui - Autocomplete multiple error

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using material-ui in React.js. When using multiple in Autocomplete it gives me the error,
Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value).filter is not a function at useAutocomplete,
The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef(Autocomplete)> component:
in ForwardRef(Autocomplete).

material-ui version - "@mui/material": "^5.6.0",

Code:

```
                        <Autocomplete
                              multiple={true}
                              disableCloseOnSelect
                              id={field.name}
                              name={field.name}
                              options={locations}
                              value={props.values.locationId}
                              size="small"
                              autoComplete={false}
                              onChange={(e, newValue) => {
                                props.setFieldValue(
                                  'locationId',
                                  newValue ? newValue : '',
                                  true,
                                );
                              }}
                              onBlur={() =>
                                props.setFieldTouched(field.name, true)
                              }
                              getOptionLabel={(option) =>
                                option['name'] ? option['name'] : ''
                              }
                              renderOption={(props, option, { selected }) => (
                                <li {...props}>
                                  <Checkbox
                                    style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
                                    checked={selected}
                                  />
                                  {option.title}
                                </li>
                              )}
                              renderInput={(params) => (
                                <TextField
                                  {...params}
                                  fullWidth
                                  size="small"
                                  placeholder={field.placeholder}
                                  variant="outlined"
                                />
                              )}
                            />
```

Comment: In all likelihood, it is an issue with the `locations` array you are using for the `options` prop.  If it is something like a string or an Object, it will throw a similar error.

Answer (score 1):

When using `multiple`, `value` must be an array (see `multiple` in the [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/#props)). I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70193988/13174944) helpful for using a controlled Autocomplete component in `multiple` mode, as you're doing here.